# How to view extra details for a product in a report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that shows products and the net value and quantity of stock movements for each one. 
Each product also has other transaction types that I would like displaying when 'clicking' on that particular product. This data is available with a separate dataset.

The report currently looks like:

```
Group | Warehouse | Product Desc | Sales £ | Sales Qty | Purchase £ | Purchase Qty
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | A         | abcde        | £100    | 20        | £50        | 10
```

`Warehouse` is visible when expanding `Group`, `Product Desc` is visible when expanding `Warehouse`.

The 2 purchase columns get the data from a 2nd dataset using lookup.

I would like to be able to expand `Product Desc` which would then show me all the other related transaction types to that product. Each transcation type also shows `Sales £` and `Sales Qty`

I don't think this is possible to include in the original dataset, as the first dataset needs only 3 transaction types to work out the specific net values. There can be up to 8 transaction types for one product.

Is a subreport a possible solution to this?

**EDIT**

Basically, what I am after, is when expanding a product in the product description column, this is then passed into the subreport as a parameter, which in turn gives you the extra data for that particular product.

I have set up a subreport and linked it to the main report by placing in a cell on the tablix. The report times out though, as loading takes to long.

Am i on the right track?

Comment: What does your current data look like? Why do you need 2 different datasets to obtain data for one record? This suggests the data isn't in a easily accessible format. I think you need to provide some data for us to work with here, and show what you want your report to look like here if you want to get a worthwhile answer. There's too little information here to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: To me, any multiple dataset, multiple subreport solution is to be avoided. you may be able to generate the lowest level dataset then use expand/ collapse to do what you want. (It's initially collpased) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-an-expand-or-collapse-action-to-an-item-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a tablix within the cell of a tablix to achieve this ([nested data regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/nested-data-regions-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)).

[image: embeded tablix]

Then to show or hide it set the visibility to toggle from the decription text box.

[image: textbox properties]